# YQL syntax when the source xml is a single node?

Tags: xml, yql

I need to use YQL to query an XML document that contains only one node.

```
<code>abc123</code>
```

All the examples for YQL I have seen assume a that you're querying a document with a hierarchical structure.

What syntax can I use? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always select "everything" with `*`, the following will work happily with XML having only one element.

```
select * from xml where url="…"
```

Comment: No, it's the name of a table.